# Find iPhone devices/device tokens in specific radius :-

Tags: iphone, find, device, token

I want to find iPhone devices/device tokens within a specific radius from particular location.

For example : Within a 25 K.M. of radius from Sydney,i want to get iPhone devices tokens.

> > I am working on ASP.NET MVC2 for this.

Let me know,if is there any API for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are only able to get details for devices that you 'know' about. Your app will need to log unique IDs for each device, and your app will need to log known locations for devices. It's then up to you to look up, from your central database, the details of the devices within a certain distance. iPhones can update significant location changes when running in the background but it's up to you to track devices and accept the limitations that that data may not always be correct. eg. If a user falls outside connectivity then you will still have an old location logged for that user.

I'm not aware of a single API that offers this services, if you're coding it then in your app you will need to register devices identifiers and location information to a central server. You will also need to create the lookup to query your data to find devices within a location. I am guessing that you might want to send push notifications, in which case your app will also need to register for notification services too.

There is no way for you to discover devices that don't have your app running and you also do not know who the owner is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.And yes i am sending Push Notifications from my MVC application.Also i am keeping the iPhone device tokens in database when new device is registered.